# for loop and if statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am running the below R code

```
n = 2
for(i in 1:n){
    if(i+1 <= n){
        for(j in i+1:n){
            print(j)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the outcome to be

```
[1] 2
```

but in fact I am getting

```
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

I am not sure where this 3 comes from. I ran the counterpart python/matlab codes, and I am getting the expected output.

Comment: try: (for j in (i+1):n)

Comment: Chapter 8.1.3 of The R Inferno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `for(j in (i+1):n){`
you want j to go from 2:2, but right now, you let j go from 1 + the numeric vector 1:2.
R differs with python/matlab in how it handles vectors (as you can see below)

try in your console and see how it works

```
1 + 1:2
```

and

```
(1 + 1):2
```